# JS script running for every element, rather than simple clicked element

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

using jQuery, I am trying to get an action assigned to a button on a form. I have 50 of these forms on a page, but every time I click one link, the form action is run 50 time!!

I ran this to check, and it comes to exactly 50

```
  `i=1
      $('.thumbs').click(function(){
        console.log(i,"Click Count");
        i++;
)};
```

this has the unhelpful effect of running the AJAX fifty times!!

am I using selectors wrong?

EDIT: [full script here](http://pastebin.com/X9TA0NQj)

EDIT: [Example of one element](http://pastebin.com/MeC7dCbh) - There are 50 of these inside a container div.

Comment: The code you have wouldn't do this, what *other* code runs on these?

Comment: Why have 50 forms? Do you have 50 form targets, or just 50 actions?

Comment: Are you binding click method inside some loop?

Comment: @Nick Craver this is the whole script http://pastebin.com/X9TA0NQj

Comment: @adam I have 50 elements in a feed, each requiring their own form

Comment: @Chinmayee I don't think so, see the pastebin above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the listener to a submit button? Make sure to return true or false if the form should be submitted or not.

Comment: Feel like uploading the HTML?

Comment: Have you tried setting the listener on the form, instead of the input? So `$('.voter').submit(function () { // your submit code here });`.
I think it might be caused because, in your code, you're not returning false on the form, you're returning false on the button click (so the submit may go through, not sure of the order of events).

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like it could be one of there two:
1) you've added 50 click listners to one button:
you could try this by adding:

```
$('.thumbs').unbind();
```

before you assign a new handler.

If this is the case, you should try to find out why and make sure you only add one.

2) the button default action is the problem:

stop default behavior:

```
$('.thumbs').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: for no good reason, it stopped behaving the way it was. Then it started again!! I added this, and it's fixed, I am so confused!!